# Perl スクリプトを動かそうとすると `"Util.bundle"は、開発元を検証できないため開けません。`

Tags: macos, perl

環境

Perl 5.20.1
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.020001 built for darwin-2level
macOS Catalina 10.15.6

題の通り、Perl スクリプトを動かそうとすると、

```
"Util.bundle"は、開発元を検証できないため開けません。
```

というダイアログが出てスクリプト起動が出来ません。

「macの設定ツール->セキュリティとプライバシー->一般->ダウンロードしたアプリケーションの許可」に `Util.bundle` の許可ボタンが出ているのでクリックするのですが、それを許可しても他の `**.bundle` が出てきます。これが際限なく出てくるのでスクリプトの起動が出来ません。

こちらの回避方法などありますでしょうか？

Comment: スクリプトは外部からダウンロードしたものでしょうか？ / mac は普段使っていないので詳しくありませんが、エラーに出ている「開発元を検証できないため開けません。」のメッセージで google 検索すると (既に試したものも含めて) 対応方法がいくつか出てくるようです。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの方法で解決しました。

[Mac「開発元を検証できないため開けません」を解決する方法! App Storeからダウンロードされないアプリを実行しよう](https://sp7pc.com/apple/mac/5734)

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```